# how to find the optimal solution of two circles

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let us have the following problem with the parameter $a\in [-3,1]$: $$\min x $$ $$(x-1)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}\le 1$$ $$(x-1)^{2}+(y+a)^{2}\le 1.$$ How to find the optimal solution? It should be the left intersection of the circles....

Comment: yes, it is the abscissa of the left extremal point of the double circular segment given by the intersection of the two circles

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/puznnjbnkx

Comment: I know how to draw a graph. Unfortunately, I need the mathematical result, I have to calculate this.

Comment: that is a simple geometric problem ..

Comment: How to express it matematically, that is the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture.

[image]

Can you see now how to use your equations to solve for x?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know now.